# Wont move past first while statement

Tags: powershell

I have been asked to change the script once again and when doing so I have ran into an issue with the script.

I have broken down the sections on the script into different sections so you can better see what i am trying to do. I am trying to choose between the TC, MonsterLock, and Cyc and have them do their own functions when i choose one of them.

The problem I am having is that once I choose one of them I can enter the next section and enter in the information for DATABASE1, DATABASE2,DATABASE3, and DATABASE4. But when I do so it loops at that section and constantly asks me

```
 This script sets up DATABASE Staging
 Sets up location you want to run staging
 Sets up location you want to run staging
 Sets up location you want to run staging
 Sets up location you want to run staging
```

This happens everytime I choose tc, MonsterLock, or Cyc. I have information in the MonsterLock as you can see but it doesnt moce past the loop and start the commands that are located inside.

```
    write-host "This script sets up DATABASE Staging"
     $ProductionDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which production do you `enter code here`want to run?(TC/MonsterLock/Cyc)"
    While($ProductionDistro -notmatch "(TC|MonsterLock|Cyc)"){
    write-host "You have entered an error" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "You must type TC or MonsterLock or Cyc"
    write-host "you typed $ProductionDistro"
    write-host "This script sets up DATABASE Staging"
    $ProductionDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which production do you `enter code here`want to ru(TC/MonsterLock/Cyc)"
     }
      while($ProductionDistro -match $TC) {
      write-host "Sets up location you want to run staging"
        $ElementDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which Element do you want to run?  (DATABASE1/DATABASE2/DATABASE3/DATABASE4/ALL)"
        While($ElementDistro -notmatch "(DATABASE1|DATABASE2|DATABASE3|DATABASE4|ALL)") {
            write-host "you have enterd an error" -ForegroundColor Red
            write-host "You must type DATABASE1 or DATABASE2 or DATABASE3 or DATABASE4 or ALL"
            write-host "you typed $ElementDistro"
            write-host "set location you want to run staging"
          $ElementDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which Element do you want to run? (DATABASE1/DATABASE2/DATABASE3/DATABASE4/ALL)"
     }
```

this is the first while statemet

```
    While($PrductionDistro -match $MonsterLock){
    write-host "Sets up location you want to run staging"
        $ElementDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which Element do you want to run? (DATABASE1/DATABASE2/DATABASE3/DATABASE4/ALL)"
        While($ElementDistro -notmatch "(DATABASE1|DATABASE2|DATABASE3|DATABASE4|ALL)") {
            write-host "you have enterd an error" -ForegroundColor Red
            write-host "You must type DATABASE1 or DATABASE2 or DATABASE3 or DATABASE4 or ALL"
            write-host "you typed $ElementDistro"
            write-host "set location you want to run staging"
          $ElementDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which Element do you want to run? (DATABASE1/DATABASE2/DATABASE3/DATABASE4/ALL)"
      }
    }
      while( $ElementDistro -match $DATABASE1 ){

     function Execute-MySqlcommand {param( [string]$Server,    #the host of the SQL server
                                            [string]$Database1,   #the name of the database
                                            [System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlcommand]$Command)  #the command to execute (name of stored command)

         $mysqlConnection = new-object System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlConnection
         $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR;DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR FOR DATABASE1.DATABASE1S2.BTXADDR;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB FOR DATABASE1.DATABASE1S3.BTXSUPB"
         $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE1.DATABASE1S2.BTXADDR;TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE1.DATABASE1S3.BTXSUPB; INSERT INTO DATABASE1.DATABASE1S3.BTXSUPB SELECT * FROM DATABASE1.DATABASE1S2.BTXSUPB; select count(*) from DATABASE1.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE1S.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE1.DATABASE.BTXSURB; select count(*) from DATABASE1S.DATABASE.BTXSUPB;"

         $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
         $Command.Connection = $mysqlConnection

         $mysqlConnection.Open()
         $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
         $mysqlConnection.Close()

         if ($Result -gt 0) {return $True} else {return $False}

     }
         function Execute-MySQLCommand {param(   [string]$Server,                #the host name of the SQL server
                    [string]$DATABASE1,             #the name of the database
                    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$Command) #the command to execute (name of stored procedure)

            $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DATABASE_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=DATABASE1;Description=DATABASE1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=Server;DATABASE=DATABASE1;DATASET=DEFAULT"

            $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
            $Command.Connection = $sqlConnection

            $sqlConnection.Open()
            $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            $sqlConnection.Close()

            if ($Result -gt 0) {return $TRUE} else {return $FALSE}
        }       

                function Copy-File {
                #.Synopsis
                # Copies all files and folders in $source folder to $destination folder, but with .copy inserted before the extension if the file already exists
                param}($DATABASE0980453.pkg,"d/DATABASE1/code_stg")

                # create destination if it's not there ...
                #mkdir $destination -force -erroraction SilentlyContinue

                foreach($original in ls $source -recurse) { 
                  $result = $original.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)
                  while(test-path $result -type leaf){ $result = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($result,"copy$([IO.Path]::GetExtension($result))") }

                  if($original.PSIsContainer) { 
                   # mkdir $result -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                 # } else {
                    copy $original.FullName -destination $result
                  }
                        cd /d/DATABASE1/code_stg
                        install  ../DATABASE0980453.pkg

       }

    while($ElementDistro -match $DATABASE2 ) {

    function execute-MySqlcommand {param( [string]$Server,    #the host of the SQL server
                                            [string]$DataBase2,   #the name of the database
                                            [System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlcommand]$Command)  #the command to execute (name of stored command)

         $mysqlConnection = new-object System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlConnection
         $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR;DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR FOR DATABASE2.DATABASE2MS2.BTXADDR;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB FOR DATABASE2.DATABASE2S3.BTXSUPB"
         $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE2.DATABASE2S2.BTXADDR;TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE2.DATABASE2S3.BTXSUPB; INSERT INTO DATABASE2.DATABASE2S3.BTXSUPB SELECT * FROM DATABASE2.DATABASE2S2.BTXSUPB; select count(*) from DATABASE2.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE2S.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE2.DATABASE.BTXSURB; select count(*) from DATABASE2S.DATABASE.BTXSUPB;"

         $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
         $Command.Connection = $mysqlConnection

         $mysqlConnection.Open()
         $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
         $mysqlConnection.Close()

         if ($Result -gt 0) {return $True} else {return $False}

 }

        function Execute-MySQLCommand {param(   [string]$Server,                #the host name of the SQL server
                    [string]$DATABASE2,             #the name of the database
                    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$Command) #the command to execute (name of stored procedure)

            $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DATABASE_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=DATABASE2; Description=DATABASE2; Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=Server;DATABASE=DATABASE2;"

            $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
            $Command.Connection = $sqlConnection

            $sqlConnection.Open()
            $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            $sqlConnection.Close()

            if ($Result -gt 0) {return $TRUE} else {return $FALSE}
            }

                function Copy-File {
                #.Synopsis
                # Copies all files and folders in $source folder to $destination folder, but with .copy inserted before the extension if the file already exists
                param}($DATABASE0980453.pkg,"d/DATABASE2/code_stg")

                # create destination if it's not there ...
                #mkdir $destination -force -erroraction SilentlyContinue

                foreach($original in ls $source -recurse) { 
                  $result = $original.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)
                  while(test-path $result -type leaf){ $result = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($result,"copy$([IO.Path]::GetExtension($result))") }

                  if($original.PSIsContainer) { 
                   # mkdir $result -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                 # } else {
                    copy $original.FullName -destination $result
                  }

                        cd /d/DATABASE2/code_stg
                        install ../DATABASE0980453.pkg
                    }

    While( $ElementDistro -match $DATABASE3 ) {

    function Execute-MySqlcommand {param( [string]$Server,    #the host of the SQL server
                                            [string]$DATABASE3,   #the name of the database
                                            [System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlcommand]$Command)  #the command to execute (name of stored command)

         $mysqlConnection = new-object System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlConnection
         $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR;DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR FOR DATABASE3.DATABASE3S2.BTXADDR;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB FOR DATABASE3.DATABASE3S3.BTXSUPB"
         $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE3.DATABASE3S2.BTXADDR;TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE3.DATABASE3S3.BTXSUPB; INSERT INTO DATABASE3.DATABASE3S3.BTXSUPB SELECT * FROM DATABASE3.DATABASE3S2.BTXSUPB; select count(*) from DATABASE3.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE3S.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE3.DATABASE.BTXSURB; select count(*) from DATABASE3S.DATABASE.BTXSUPB;"

         $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
         $Command.Connection = $mysqlConnection

         $mysqlConnection.Open()
         $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
         $mysqlConnection.Close()

         if ($Result -gt 0) {return $True} else {return $False}
}
             function Execute-MySQLCommand {param(   [string]$Server,                #the host name of the SQL server
                        [string]$DATABASE3,             #the name of the database
                        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$Command) #the command to execute (name of stored procedure)

                    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DATABASE_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=DATABASE3;Description=DATABASE3;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=Server;DATABASE=DATABASE3;"

                    $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
                    $Command.Connection = $sqlConnection

                    $sqlConnection.Open()
                    $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    $sqlConnection.Close()

                    if ($Result -gt 0) {return $TRUE} else {return $FALSE}
    }
        cd /d/DATABASE3/code_stg
            install ../DATABASE0980453.pkg
        }

                function Copy-File {
                #.Synopsis
                # Copies all files and folders in $source folder to $destination folder, but with .copy inserted before the extension if the file already exists
                param}($DATABASE0980453.pkg,"d/DATABASE3/code_stg")

                # create destination if it's not there ...
                #mkdir $destination -force -erroraction SilentlyContinue

                foreach($original in ls $source -recurse) { 
                  $result = $original.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)
                  while(test-path $result -type leaf){ $result = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($result,"copy$([IO.Path]::GetExtension($result))") }

                  if($original.PSIsContainer) { 
                   # mkdir $result -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                 # } else {
                    copy $original.FullName -destination $result
                  }
    While($ElementDistro -match $DATABASE4 ) {

       function Execute-MySqlcommand {param( [string]$Server,    #the host of the SQL server
                                            [string]$DATABASE4,   #the name of the database
                                            [System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlcommand]$Command)  #the command to execute (name of stored command)

         $mysqlConnection = new-object System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlConnection
         $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR;DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR FOR DATABASE4.DATABASE42.BTXADDR;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB FOR DATABASE4.DATABASE4S3.BTXSUPB"
         $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE4.DATABASE4S2.BTXADDR;TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE4.DATABASE4S3.BTXSUPB; INSERT INTO DATABASE4.DATABASE4S3.BTXSUPB SELECT * FROM DATABASE4.DATABASE4S2.BTXSUPB; select count(*) from DATABASE4.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE4S.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE4.DATABASE.BTXSURB; select count(*) from DATABASE4S.DATABASE.BTXSUPB;"

         $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
         $Command.Connection = $mysqlConnection

         $mysqlConnection.Open()
         $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
         $mysqlConnection.Close()

         if ($Result -gt 0) {return $True} else {return $False}
}       
        function Execute-MySQLCommand {param(   [string]$Server,                #the host name of the SQL server
                    [string]$DATABASE4,             #the name of the database
                    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$Command) #the command to execute (name of stored procedure)

    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DATABASE_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=DATABASE4;Description=DATABASE4;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=Server;DATABASE=TF90PVS;"

    $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
    $Command.Connection = $sqlConnection

    $sqlConnection.Open()
    $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $sqlConnection.Close()

    if ($Result -gt 0) {return $TRUE} else {return $FALSE}
}

function Copy-File {
#.Synopsis
# Copies all files and folders in $source folder to $destination folder, but with .copy inserted before the extension if the file already exists
param}($DATABASE0980453.pkg,,"d/DATABASE4/code_stg")

# create destination if it's not there ...
#mkdir $destination -force -erroraction SilentlyContinue

foreach($original in ls $source -recurse) { 
  $result = $original.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)
  while(test-path $result -type leaf){ $result = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($result,"copy$([IO.Path]::GetExtension($result))") }

  if($original.PSIsContainer) { 
   # mkdir $result -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 # } else {
    copy $original.FullName -destination $result
  } 

    cd /d/DATABASE4/code_st
    install ../DATABASE0980453.pkg
}
     While($ElementDistro -match $ALL ){

     function Execute-MySQLCommand {param(  [string]$Server,              #the host name of the SQL server
                    [string]$DATABASE1,$DATABASE2,$DATABASE3,$DATABASE4,                #the name of the database
                    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$Command) #the command to execute (name of stored procedure)

    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "(DATABASE_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=DATABASE1;Description=DATABASE1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=Server;DATABASE=DATABASE1;DATASET=DEFAULT;),(DATABASE_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=DATABASE2; Description=DATABASE2; Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=Server;DATABASE=DATABASE2;),(DATABASE_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=DATABASE3;Description=DATABASE3;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=Server;DATABASE=DATABASE3;),(DATABASE_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=DATABASE4;Description=DATABASE4;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=Server;DATABASE=TF90PVS;)"

    $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
    $Command.Connection = $sqlConnection

    $sqlConnection.Open()
    $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $sqlConnection.Close()

    if ($Result -gt 0) {return $TRUE} else {return $FALSE}
 }  

    install ../DATABASE0980453.pkg
     }
```

Second While statement

```
 While($ProductionDistro -match $Cyc) {
 write-host "Sets up location you want to run staging"
        $ElementDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which Element do you want to run? (DATABASE1/DATABASE2/DATABASE3/DATABASE4/ALL)"
        While($ElementDistro -notmatch "(DATABASE1|DATABASE2|DATABASE3|DATABASE4|ALL)") {
            write-host "you have enterd an error" -ForgroundColor Red
            write-host "You must type DATABASE1 or DATABASE2 or DATABASE3 or DATABASE4 or ALL"
            write-host "you typed $ElementDistro"
            write-host "set location you want to run staging"
          $ElementDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which Element do you want to run? (DATABASE1/DATABASE2/DATABASE3/DATABASE4/ALL)"
 }
}
}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop beginning `while($ProductionDistro -match $TC) {` does not appear to modify `$ProductionDistro` so once you get into that loop it will go round forever. The same appears to apply to the other `while($ProductionDistro...` loops.

For a `while` loop to terminate you must update some of the values used in the condition to make the condition no longer evaluate to something true.

Comment: how would I change to modify $ProductionDistro ro how would I terminate the while loop so i could enter into another one. I am just learning how to write scripts for powershell so I am lost when it comes to adding in stuff

Comment: Why do you need to use a `while` loop at all? It looks to me as though you just want `if($ProductionDistro`...

Comment: I went and read about it and i made the mistake of doing while loops. I have changed my script to use switch loops and if loops and it passes between the instances.

Comment: thank you for the help. I had a lot of reading to do to understand what you meant when it didn't modify the $PductionDistro and how to terminate a while loop to stop form running a infinite loop